# how to compile a javascript file before impoted by raw-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, raw-loader

I want to import a .js file as string with raw-loader, however the .js file is written with ES6 module, I want to compile and bundle the file with babel and webpack before import it by raw-loader.

In my code, I want to use like:

```
import SomeScriptsString from '!raw-loader!./my-module-file.js'

// use SomeScriptsString as a string
```

Could any one can help?